# array error out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

I am having problem when running my code. It compiles fine, but when I run it I get this error.
The data3.txt file is a series of numbers.

**ERROR:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at database3.main(database3.java:6)
```

My **CODE:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class  database3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

File inputDataFile = new File(args[0]);
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner("data3.txt"); // READ DATA FROM FILE   
int foundvalue = 0;
int d = inputFile.nextInt();
int list[] = new int[d];

for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    list[i] = inputFile.nextInt();


System.out.println("Database Server is Ready for Number Lookups!");

Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in); //Get user input
double input;
while (stdin.hasNext()){
  input = stdin.nextDouble();
  boolean found = false;
  System.out.println("The number to look up is: " +input);

  for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
     if(list[j] == input){
        found = true;  
        break;   
     }    
  }
  if(found == true){
     System.out.println(input +" is in the database");
  }
  else{
     System.out.println(input +" is NOT in the database");
  }
}

System.out.println("Goodbye!");
System.exit(0);

}     
}
```

Comment: How is this related to javascript..?

Comment: 14 
21 
222 
210 
-44 
78 
88 
96 
0 
-1 
88 
7890 
567 
999 
-101

Comment: Little advice: don't use `if(found == true){`. `if(found){` is enough and you will not make mistake by assigning boolean value (`=` instead of `==`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` means there is an array of *zero elements*.

I suspect the array in question is `args`, which will be an array with no elements if *no command-line arguments were specified*. `args[0]` is also conveniently on *line 6*, as indicated by the Exception message.

Compare with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (args.length < 1) {
     throw new Exception("Specify a filename!");
  }
  File inputDataFile = new File(args[0]);
  ..
```

Then, pass the appropriate number of command-line arguments - namely, specify a filename - when running the program :)

Comment: I don't think I need that part we were given a base code to modify. Now i have this error. Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at database3.main(database3.java:7)

Answer (score 0):

Array Out of bound mainly occur due to more use of variable in array or the first index of an array is 0, which means the last index of an array is one less than its length. So, knowing that, take a look at the condition in your for loop and see if can find and fix the problem.Try out this it may fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

it means your  `args[]` array has no elements in it

because you haven't passed any over here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

So `args[0]` holds no value and this is the reason behind your error

Answer (score 0):

args is an array of your input strings.

Your line 6:

```
File inputDataFile = new File(args[0]);
```

Is throwing an index out of bounds error with index 0,
which means that args is an empty String array, 
that you haven't provided any input string values.

Try putting input string values when you run the program.

To Run a java program with command line inputs,
at the directory of your .java file, type:

```
java program "input"
```